# Is it possible to run stress at the same time as vmstat/iostat etc?

Tags: 12.04, bash, stress-testing

I have written two scripts-one to stress the system and one to run `vmstat` etc. I am able to get the file outputs for `vmstat` etc but am not able to get the ones for `stress` as it tells me that the file cannot be found no matter how much I tweak the pathname.

Is it therefore possible to run `stress` at the same time as `vmstat` etc? What I want is a before and after picture of the system under stress which I can graph.

Which of these is the best option(or only option) to do this:

1. run `vmstat` etc, then run `stress`, then run `vmstat` etc to compare?
2. run `vmstat` and `stress` within the same script?
3. run `stress` and get the output to file(if this is even possible?)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28781296/is-it-possible-to-run-stress-at-the-same-time-as-vmstat-iostat-etc

Comment: yes I asked it here because no one would answer on stack overflow as they always send you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this:

1. start `vmstat` with its output directed to a log file, and background it `&`
2. [optional] `sleep` for a few seconds (to get a baseline) `&&` [when `sleep` exits]
3. start `stress`

e.g.

```
vmstat 1 20 > vmstat.log & sleep 5 && stress --cpu 8 --io 4 --vm 2 --vm-bytes 128M --timeout 10s
```

in this case, giving

```
$ cat vmstat.log 
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ------cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0      0 780804  70184 855824    0    0   221    52  187  512  7  2 90  0  0
 0  0      0 780804  70184 855824    0    0     0     0  110  312  2  0 98  0  0
 0  0      0 780752  70184 855824    0    0     0     0   80  220  0  1 100  0  0
 0  0      0 780752  70192 855824    0    0     0    28  103  222  3  0 97  1  0
 0  0      0 780752  70192 855824    0    0     0     0  115  298  2  0 98  0  0
 2  0      0 780176  70192 855824    0    0     0     0   93  250  0  1 99  0  0
12  0      0 657848  70200 855824    0    0     0  2144  986 2014 60 40  1  0  0
14  0      0 657608  70208 855824    0    0     0    20 1418 2194 61 40  0  0  0
15  0      0 686376  70216 855824    0    0     0    20 1465 3681 58 42  0  0  0
14  0      0 598072  70228 855824    0    0     0    24 1503 3507 59 41  0  0  0
16  0      0 632880  70252 855812    0    0     0    96 1514 3235 63 38  0  0  0
14  0      0 656944  70280 856112    0    0     0   416 1465 2710 64 37  0  0  0
15  0      0 722508  70428 855764    0    0     0  2012 1184 2991 74 27  0  0  0
14  1      0 673924  70456 855768    0    0     0   140 1003 2344 65 35  0  0  0
14  0      0 565940  70464 855776    0    0     0    20  850 1953 60 40  0  0  0
 3  0      0 778332  70492 855760    0    0     0   140  906 1987 60 41  0  0  0
 0  0      0 782516  70500 855752    0    0     0    16  126  342  1  0 99  1  0
 0  0      0 782584  70500 855776    0    0     0     0   96  210  0  1 100  0  0
 1  0      0 788496  70500 855776    0    0     0     0  204  430 10  0 90  0  0
 0  0      0 788664  70500 855776    0    0     0     0  906 2988 16  2 82  0  0
```

Comment: That works! How can I filter the output though to certain columns in excel? And remove the line at the top which says "memory, swap, io etc?"

Comment: My go-to for that would be awk: you could use something like `awk 'NR > 1 {print $13,$14,$15}' vmstat.log` (or, equivalently, pipe the vmstat output through `awk 'NR > 1 {print $13,$14,$15}'` **before** sending it to the file). Alternatively, you could use Excel's import wizard to select columns.

Comment: when I put it like this, it doesn't print any data. what might I be doing wrong?  vmstat $INT $CNT  awk 'NR > 1 {print $13,$14,$15}'> cpu.log & sleep 5 && stress --cpu $cores -t $seconds_to_run

Comment: You seem to be missing the **pipe** `|` between your vmstat command and the awk command: `vmstat $INT $CNT | awk ...`